# Why would SQLite exception with "busy" for DELETE commands, but return successfully for CREATE IF NOT EXISTS?

Tags: c#, sqlite, locking

I have the following code snippet in my application:

```
            try
            {
                mycommand = new SQLiteCommand(cnn);
                mycommand.CommandText = "delete from addresses;";
                rowsUpdated = mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (SQLiteException ex)
            {
                if (ex.ResultCode == SQLiteErrorCode.Busy)
                {
                    cnn.Close();
                    cnn.Open();

                    try
                    {
                        mycommand = new SQLiteCommand(cnn);
                        mycommand.CommandText = "create table if not exists addresses(ADDRNUMBER TEXT, ... , PRIMARY KEY (ADDRNUMBER...));";
                        //returns immediately, not busy
                        rowsUpdated = mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        mycommand = new SQLiteCommand(cnn);
                        mycommand.CommandText = "delete from addresses;";
                        //still returns busy
                        rowsUpdated = mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (SQLiteException ex_l)
                    {
                        if (ex_l.ResultCode == SQLiteErrorCode.Busy)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("delete still busy");
                        }
                    }

                }
```

From what I've been able to find online, "BUSY" is only returned when the database file is used by another *process*, whereas "LOCKED" is returned if the database file is being used by the same *connection*.

Anyway, whenever I run a delete command, I am returned a "BUSY" exception -- but if I turn around and immediately try to do something else with the database, it works fine.

I'm at a loss as to how I can even debug this -- I've double-checked the codebase, and the only SQLite statements that run are these `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS...` and `DELETE FROM...` queries. As for the exception itself, it only returns "database is locked", which doesn't seem particularly helpful in tracking this down, either.

Any insight? Am I just fundamentally misusing SQLite?

Comment: Have you tried figuring out what type of lock it is? That may very well be the clue of why this is happening.

Comment: @Gaspa79 I'm not sure how I'd do that -- where would I start?

Comment: Since your code works in another computer I'd say that maybe you have an open process that's using the database at the moment? I'd try using this first: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/opened_files_view.html . Also if you're desperate and want to just make it work I'd also try restarting the computer (I'm dead serious).

Comment: @Gaspa79 One of the first things I tried. Unfortunately, even when I delete the database file (which the program recreates as part of running), I run up against this error.

Comment: @Gaspa79 I have now confirmed that the reason it was _not_ happening for my friend was unrelated. It is happening to everyone.